# Why my PostUpdateOrder Plugin executed twice CRM 2013

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2013

After the user validate an order, the status of the order is set so validated and it is sent to another system X, the problem is that the plugin is fired twiced in some cases even more than twice and that lead to sending this entity multiple time to the system X. I tried to correct that by using the context.depth, but all the time is equal to 1.

JS Method:

```
Validate: function () {
        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("eoz_validated").setValue(true);
        Xrm.Page.data.entity.save();
        ABE.Order.HideVisibleField();
        Xrm.Page.ui.clearFormNotification('ProductError');
    }
}
```

Plugin Execute method:

```
protected void ExecutePostOrderUpdate(LocalPluginContext localContext)
    {
        if (localContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("localContext");
        }
        if (localContext.PluginExecutionContext.Depth > 1)
        {
            return;
        }
        tracingService = localContext.TracingService;
        var order = (Entity)localContext.PluginExecutionContext.InputParameters["Target"];

        bool isValidated = order.GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("abe_isValidated").Value : false;

        if (isValidated )
        {
            SendToSystemX(localContext.OrganizationService, order.Id);
            SendProductsToOwner(localContext.OrganizationService, order.Id);
        }

        var statecode = order.Contains("statecode") ? order.GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("statecode").Value : -1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If your plugin is registered to trigger on update of `"eoz_validated"` and also updates `"eoz_validated"` then you can have an infinite execution loop.

To avoid this, before updating your context entity, reinstantiate it:

```
var updatedEntity = new Entity { LogicalName = context.LogicalName, Id = context.Id };
```

This removes all attributes that would otherwise have been updated such as `"eoz_validated"` which is contained within the context entity. Note that in your code you store the context entity within a variable called `order`.

I'm just guessing here (and don't have 50 reputation to ask a question). If this is happening in your code then presumably it's within `SendToSystemX(IOrganizationService, Guid)` or `SendProductsToOwner(IOrganizationService, Guid)`.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I removed the SendToSystemX(IOrganizationService, Guid) and SendProductsToOwner(IOrganizationService, Guid). the plugin still executes twice.